# Invalid name; names must not begin with punctuation, contain "@", ":", "#", "\", or blanks, or end in punctuation or digits following punctuation

Tags: postgresql, repository, sqitch

I had download my repository on my local computer. When I'm trying to use command SQITCH TAG i receive an error message look like this:

```
Syntax error in sqitch.plan at line 7: Invalid name; names must not begin with punctuation, contain "@", ":", "#", "\", or blanks, or end in punctuation or digits following punctuation
```

That is look somehow there is a problem with my sqitch.plan file. This line include polish signs and start with one of the signs which contains an error, but other members of the team have the same line and there it works fine. Here is the line:

## #10094: Dodanie uwzglêdniania cen wzorcowych do wyliczanego raportu zwrotnego, wartoæ sprzeda¿y wyliczana z iloci surowej, rednia cena wyliczana ju¿ przy u¿yciu iloci poprawnej.

My settings in sqitch.conf:

```
[core]
    engine = pg
    # plan_file = sqitch.plan
    # top_dir = .
# [engine "pg"]
    # target = db:pg:
    # registry = sqitch
    # client = C:\pgsql\bin\psql.exe
[target "server1"]
    uri = db:pg://server1/dbname
[target "server2"]
    uri = db:pg://server2/dbname
[target "server3"]
    uri = db:pg://server3/dbname
[target "server4"]
    uri = db:pg://server4/dbname
[target "server5"]
    uri = db:pg://server5/dbname
[target "server6"]
    uri = db:pg://server6/dbname
[target "server7"]
    uri = db:pg://server7/dbname
[target "server8"]
    uri = db:pg://server8/dbname
[engine "pg"]
    target = server1
```

Anybody met this problem? Any other settings may have impact?

I want to print list of tags used in project to describe changes in database (PostgreSQL).

sqitch.plan file:

```
1 %syntax-version=1.0.0

2 %project=test_project

3 %uri=https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch-intro/

4

5 cluster/funth 2019-02-06T10:42:23Z Maciej nowak <mnowak@firma.pl> # Initial cluster/move_month function release.

6 dea/table_ata_1 2019-02-06T12:50:51Z Maciej nowak <mnowak@firma.pl> # #9564: Automatyzacja: Usystematyzowanie funkcji D- dodanie kolumny
 
7 mona\func_f_ 2019-02-07T09:33:31Z S³awomir kowalski <skowalski@firma.pl> # #10094: Dodanie uwzglêdniania cen wzorcowych do wyliczanego raportu zwrotnego, wartoæ sprzeda¿y wyliczana z iloci surowej, rednia cena wyliczana ju¿ przy u¿yciu iloci poprawnej.

8 mona\func_f_up 2019-02-07T11:17:47Z S³awomir kowalski <skowalski@firma.pl> # #10094: Dodanie uwzglêdniania cen wzorcowych do wyliczanego raportu zwrotnego, wartoæ sprzeda¿y wyliczana z iloci surowej, rednia cena wyliczana ju¿ przy u¿yciu iloci poprawnej.

9 moa\func_awmm 2019-02-08T07:44:12Z S³awomir kowalski <skowalski@firma.pl> # #10275: Dodanie uwzglêdniania identyfikatora wielookresu przy dodawaniu pustych linii do tabeli z danymi

10 weyf\func_uv_old 2019-02-11T07:30:20Z Robert kowalski <rkowalski@firma.pl> # Zmiana testowa
```

Comment: `Syntax error in sqitch.plan` but you say you have posted `sqitch.conf`

Comment: I added sqitch.plan file content to my post

Comment: You seem to switch from forward-slash to backward-slash on line 7 in your path. It also ends with a trailing "_" - that seems unusual to me.